# Flash will not load images when embedded inside of lightwindow

Tags: javascript, flash, lightwindow

I posted a question similar to this not so long ago however I have trawled through the forums and could not find an answer...

I am using Lightwindow which is a version of lightbox that can have ANY form of content and DOES support .swf files.

I have linked the test link on my page to activate lightwindow and open the swf file. Light window opens the window to the correct size but does not display any content. If I go directly to the flash file then all the test images load... http://tinyurl.com/6no86pw

The page in question can be found @ http://tinyurl.com/89twd9o and the test link is called 'link name'.

Here is the code for that link:

```
    <a href="http://www.monsterbox.co.uk/ollie/lightwindow/gallery/gallery.swf"    class="lightwindow" params="lightwindow_width=800,lightwindow_height=345" >Link Name</a>
```

I understand that something along the lines of

```
    <param name="base" value="images" />
```

would be added inside of the object however in this case I don't understand how it works.

Thanks

C

Comment: Use an http inspector such as charles/fiddler/firebug to find out what's happening to those requests.

Answer (score 0):

Your swf is trying (and failing) to load `http://www.monsterbox.co.uk/ollie/gallery.xml`. I assume logic in your swf relies on this data to progress.

Comment: but if you go directly to the swf file it loads fine

Comment: I'd suggest wrestling control back from this BlaBlaBox, writing your own HTML to host the SWF file, and placing that in the box. It's been such a long time since I butted up against relative path issues that I can't remember how to fix it.